# Profile only a single function (or cost center) with GHC

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I am trying to profile some Haskell code using the GHC profiling tools.  The cost center I am most interested in, however, is dominated currently by a bunch of initialization code that I don't really care about.

My code looks roughly, like this:

```
main = do
  x <- lotsOfInitialization
  print $ {-# SCC "myCostCenter" #-} interestingPart x
```

In my actual code, the `lotsOfInitialization` part is taking ~98% of the time and so it's difficult to see with any granularity what is happening inside `interestingPart`.

I thought that only annotating in one place (and not using `-fprof-auto`) would be enough, but the report I'm getting still shows all the function calls.

I also tried a strictness annotation on `x`, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Is there some way to tell GHC to ignore the initialization code, or to only focus on the parts I want?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [ghc manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#rts-options-for-heap-profiling) you can do heap profiling on certain cost centers by e.g. using  -hc⟨name⟩ or  -hy⟨type⟩.

I couldn't find a solution that does something similar for time profiling though.

**EDIT:**

I did actuall manage to find a way to conveniently do what you need for both allocation and time profiling. If you use the [profiteur](https://github.com/jaspervdj/profiteur) visualizer for `.prof` files you can look at the performance profile of just a certain cost centre as a nicely formatted tree-map.